# Spotipy doesn't return track info, when in song's name there is a ' in the middle of a word or a speacil character

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am using Spotipy's `search` function to get me a list of track IDs that later are used for a small Machine Learning project I am having. I made a big database of songs, and some of them has words such as "Don't", "I'm" and "We're", or "Ü", "é".

Now the problem is that I do want these tracks IDs for all the songs, and I know for fact that these songs are popular enough that Spotify has them for sure, but it is consistent that these characters are doing me some problems.

- I tried to remove the ' from the words, and it kinda worked? but I need to be sure 100 percents the song I get is the song I asked for so because there are words that removing the ' gives them a whole different meaning, and I gave one example for such a word previously: We're -> Were.
- I tried to change every time there was a word with ', to %27, which is what happens inside right before sending the request, but again this is not helping in solving the general case of any special character.
- I tried to load the strings as utf-8 strings. Didn't work either.
- I tried to follow using debugger through the path that gets the final say in the query request inside the guts of the `search` function, I do remember playing around the models.py module that comes with it but it doesn't seem to work, or I don't remember how I did it before.

Another type of songs that get rejected are songs where the artists that I attached to the song is not the first artist mentioned in the list, now I can and will change it to search just to the track name, but that might result me with different songs than the one I am looking for.

For this problem, I don't really know what to do.

I would like to know if there is a way to by-pass it automatically so I won't have to put the songs and artists names by hand into the GUI Spotify Web API has.

Many thanks in advance!

**Update!**

I went and tried to use the [online console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/) Spotify supply for all its api commands and discovered that even there, the songs won't be found. For example, I get zero responses when trying to find the song: "Don't Stop The Music" with the query: `"track:Don't Stop The Music artist:"Rihanna"` but do find the right results when changing it to `"track:Don t Stop The Music artist:Rihanna"`. So I don't know if there is more things to be done there, or this is an end point where the solution is just in spotify developers team's hands. In the meanwhile most of the ' problems were solved by just changing ' to space character.

Comment: _"... solving the general case of any special character"_ Have you tried [URL quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting) the strings? `from urllib.parse import quote`; `[quote(special) for special in ["Don't", "I'm", "We're", "Ü", "é"]]` => `['Don%27t', 'I%27m', 'We%27re', '%C3%9C', '%C3%A9']`

Comment: in models.py (which is under the requests package) there is a core function called _encode_params(params) (I say 'core' as I can find pythonic declaration of this function) that does exactly that, and yet it doesn't give me the results I needed.